# Get content of a Stripe\Checkout\Session in gravity form context

Tags: php, stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin

I built a gravity form and i'm using the hook [gform_stripe_fulfillment](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_stripe_fulfillment/) to intercept a [Stripe\Checkout\Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions) when it success.

Then inside, of my function, i want to get 2 attributes of the Stripe\Checkout\Session :

- apiKey
- payment_intent

My problem is : i don't know how to manipulate this object to get this information in the context of gravity form.
If i do a var_dump of the variable $session, it looks like this (this is just the beginning of the content) :

```
Stripe\Checkout\Session::__set_state(array(
   'saveWithParent' => false,
   '_opts' => 
  Stripe\Util\RequestOptions::__set_state(array(
     'headers' => 
    array (
    ),
     'apiKey' => 'sk_test_510uY9pCOg5xUH23xyvsUYPPXZbruPgf1ASjkxFZrZkhJLIxiSw4XWVQm2D1oNOiVPMeaeLKPJ2OkuwnRPCKPJGb500xy11IsI6',
     'apiBase' => NULL,
  )),
...
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You should be able to use `$session->payment_intent` to access the Payment Intent.  That said, I'm not sure how or why you would want to get the API key.  Can you edit your question to add more context about what you're trying to do, and include the code that creates `$session` and the `var_dump()` call where you're getting the output you shared?

Comment: I confirm that $session->payment_intent works. Thanks.
About the api key : I try to get the fees for a payment Intent. So i need to do an other call to retrieve the payment intent, and for this i need the secret key.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @justin-michael, this is how to do :

```
$payment_intent_id = $session->payment_intent;

$secret_api_key = gf_stripe()->get_secret_api_key();
```